# on click en lista con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una lista y quiero que al hacer clic en un li de esta lista aparezca un alert.

html:

```
<ul class="lista">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").append('<ul class="lista">' +
          '<li>Coffee</li>' +
          '<li>Tea</li>' +
          '<li>Milk</li>' +
        '</ul>'
    );

    $(".lista li").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");
    });

});
```

Tengo ese codigo pero no me funciona

Comment: seguro que incluiste jquery? por que yo estoy probando tu código y funciona

Comment: Tanto el HTML como el jQuery están correctos. ¿Sabes que error te aparece en la consola de tu navegador?

Comment: dberías tener primero la llamada a jquery y luego este código que escribes en otra tag script pues si funciona

Comment: @element  esta incluido jquerry, de hecho la lista la genero con jquery

Comment: comaprte el código completo

Comment: @element editado

Comment: por cierto en la consola no me da ningún error

Comment: te publico una respuesta dame 3 min @umu

Comment: @element ok perfecto

Comment: listo indicame si sirvió @umu

Comment: @element gracias!

Comment: Esta pregunta la has hecho dos veces, considera eliminarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente

Veo que en tu código de JQuery declaras que acceda por medio de un elemento con una class `.add` por lo tanto ese elemento debe ser declarado de manera estática dentro de la estructura de tu HTML

Yo en este ejemplo declaro un `div` que contendrá dicha lista de este modo

```
<div class="add"></div>
```

Por último recuerda que

1. Debes tener el elemento HTML con la class add
2. Declaras el `script` que contiene el llamado a tu librería JQuery
3. Declara en otro `script` el código para generar la lista y efectuar el código que responde al momento de hacer clic

---

> Si pruebas nuevamente este código ya te debe estar arrojando el alert
>   por cada li de tu lista

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="add"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").append('<ul class="lista">' +
          '<li>Coffee</li>' +
          '<li>Tea</li>' +
          '<li>Milk</li>' +
        '</ul>'
    );

    $(".lista li").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **** la class add, gracias! :)

Answer (score -1):

> Ahora que compartes más código, intenta hacer lo siguiente para descartar que sea problema del DOM:

```
setTimeout(function(){  
  $(".lista li").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");
    });
}, 100);
```

Desconocía que on.click sobré .click es mejor por motivos de optimizar memoria y trabajar para elementos agregados dinámicamente, tienen razón los demás, cómo lo estás haciendo funciona, me anticipe con la respuesta.

Comment: de hecho si pruebas el código del OP es perfectamente funcional, su error no es esto y esta en otra parte

Comment: además si consideraste que esto resuelve el problema, no es solo decirle intenta esto, sino argumentar el por que

Comment: nadamas te aclaro que yo no te vote negativo